# Matlab - Shuffling matrix values based on some conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following two matrices which are outputs of a procedure. The size of the matrices may change but both matrices will always be the same size: `size(TwoHopMat_1) == size(Final_matrix)`

**Example:**

```
TwoHopMat_1 =

     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0


Final_matrix =

 1     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     1
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     1
```

Now I need to shuffle the final_matrix such that i meet the following conditions after shuffling:

1. Every column should have a minimum of one 1s
2. If i have a 1 in a particular position of TwoHopMat_1 then that particular position should not have 1 after shuffling.

The conditions should work even if we give matrices of size 100x100.

Comment: You need to have in your result matrix the same number of "1's" as in the Final_matrix?

Comment: Yes and well spread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first step: set one element of each column of the result matrix ,that is not 1 in Final_matrix ,to 1

second step: then remaining ones randomly inserted into positions of the result matrix that are not 1 in Final_matrix and are not 1 in the first step result

```
TwoHopMat_1=[...
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0];
Final_matrix=[...
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     1];
[row col] = size(Final_matrix);
result = zeros(row ,col);
%condition 1 & 2 :
notTwoHop = ~TwoHopMat_1;
s= sum(notTwoHop,1);
c= [0 cumsum(s(1:end - 1))];
f= find(notTwoHop);
r = floor(rand(1, col) .* s) + 1;
i = c + r;
result(f(i)) = 1;
%insert remaining ones randomly into the result
f= find(~(result | TwoHopMat_1));
i = randperm(numel(f), sum(Final_matrix(:))-col);
result(f(i)) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
function [result_matrix] = shuffle_matrix(TwoHopMat_1, Final_matrix)

  % Condition number 2
  ones_mat = ones(size(TwoHopMat_1));
  temp_mat = abs(TwoHopMat_1 - ones_mat);

  % Condition number 1
  ones_to_remove = abs(sum(sum(temp_mat)) - sum(sum(Final_matrix)));
  while ones_to_remove > 0
    % Random matrix entry
    i = floor((size(Final_matrix, 1) * rand())) + 1;
    j = floor((size(Final_matrix, 2) * rand())) + 1;

    if temp_mat(i,j) == 1
      temp_mat(i,j) = 0;
      ones_to_remove = ones_to_remove - 1;
    end    
  end
  result_matrix = temp_mat;
end
```

**Note:** this solution uses brute force.

Comment: Thanks alot it works, however i get all zeros in columns 2 times out of 15.